# Symfony 3 an exception occurred while executing SELECT NEXTVAL

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-3.3

I get this error when I try to insert something

> An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT
>   NEXTVAL('oficinas_id_seq')':
>
> SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR: no existe la relación
>   «oficinas_id_seq» LINE 1: SELECT NEXTVAL('oficinas_id_seq')

This is my entity

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Oficinas
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="oficinas")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Oficinas
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="SEQUENCE")
     * @ORM\SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="public.oficinas_id_seq", allocationSize=1, initialValue=1)
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="descripcion", type="string", length=100, nullable=false)
     */
    private $descripcion;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="tu", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    private $tu;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="ts", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    private $ts = 'now()';



    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set descripcion
     *
     * @param string $descripcion
     *
     * @return Oficinas
     */
    public function setDescripcion($descripcion)
    {
        $this->descripcion = $descripcion;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get descripcion
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDescripcion()
    {
        return $this->descripcion;
    }
}
```

I´ve test this doctrine commands but didn't work

> php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import Bundle annotation php
>   bin/console generate:doctrine:entities Bundle php bin/console
>   doctrine:schema:update --force

Any idea?

Comment: Try running the `doctrine:schema:diff` then migrate: `doctrine:migrations:migrate`. Seems your table has not been created yet\ for `Oficinas`. Guess I should have asked if you were using doctrine migrations first.... Sorry

Comment: Hi @AndrewNolan command doctrine:schema:diff is not defined. I made the postgres database first and then migrate it to symfony

Comment: Yea, if you are not using doctrine migrations, then neither command i posted will work. Sorry for confusing more if I did.

Comment: I made a validate and it return: the database schema is not in sync with the current mapping file

Comment: What type of database are you using ? Can you show the SQL used to create the table `oficinas` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just run this command to see the diff between code and DB

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql
```